# In Bundler, how can I override a dependency's version requirements for its own dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have a couple of needs in my application for which working on edge Rails (3.1) would help me complete my task faster.

The problem is that one of the gems I depend on doesn't yet officially support Rails 3.1, and it has a "~> 3.0.0" railties dependency, which creates a dependency conflict and bundler can't resolve my dependencies. Can I override that requirement in my app's Gemfile somehow, or is my only workaround to fork my dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, branching it is the only way to unravel that. Or, being more hacky, modifying the /vendor local installation of the gem.

Comment: I think forking the gem is a good solution.
It may seem like overkill, but the chances are something may break, and you'll have to submit a patch anyway.

Comment: One of the few things about the Ruby ecosystem that makes me long for .Net's `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"                           newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>` or maven's dependency overwriting. I was hoping to use the "fork if something breaks" approach...