# Bundler dependency ~> doesn't recognize beta versions from github properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, bundler

Here's a part of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', "3.1.0"
gem "sprockets", :git => 'git://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets.git', :tag => "v2.0.0.beta.13"
```

When try to do bundle install, it says that rails 3.1.0 depend on sprockets ~> 2.0.0
Apparantely, this beta version that is downloaded from github is not recognized as a newer version. However, if I put `gem "rails", "3.1.0.rc5"` in my Gemfile it works fine.

How do I tell bundler to ignore this sprocket dependency or otherwise resolve this issue? And whose issue is that: bundler's or sprockets'?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.1'
gem 'sprockets', :git => 'git://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets.git', :tag => 'v2.0.0.beta.13'
```

It's possible that your pinning rails to 3.1.0 actually forces the use of the 2.0.0 Sprockets gem. That said, I'm not sure that using a soft pin to rails 3.1 is going to ease out the dependency from rails to sprockets and let you use the beta version instead of the "release" one...

Comment: No, it still doesn't work saying `Could not find gem 'sprockets (~> 2.0.0)', required by 'rails (~> 3.1.0)', in any of the sources`

Comment: Actually, I just found another question that answers yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361996/in-bundler-how-can-i-override-a-dependencys-version-requirements-for-its-own-de